# Optimizing max similarity for WSD in Python

Tags: python, performance

I have [a library](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd) for simple Word Sense Disambiguation (WSD).

I have a function for WSD based on the sum of maximum similarity score for every word. But it's slow because it iterates through all words in the input sentence and then finds the max similarity score between the every sense of each word.

How could I speed up the `max_similarity` function? (Cython tricks are welcomed)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
User requested feature. WSD by maximizing similarity. 
"""

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.corpus import wordnet_ic as wnic
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def similarity_by_path(sense1, sense2, option="path"):
    """ Returns maximum path similarity between two senses. """
    if option.lower() in ["path", "path_similarity"]: # Path similaritys
        return max(wn.path_similarity(sense1,sense2), 
                   wn.path_similarity(sense1,sense2))
    elif option.lower() in ["wup", "wupa", "wu-palmer", "wu-palmer"]: # Wu-Palmer 
        return wn.wup_similarity(sense1, sense2)
    elif option.lower() in ['lch', "leacock-chordorow"]: # Leacock-Chodorow
        if sense1.pos != sense2.pos: # lch can't do diff POS
            return 0
        return wn.lch_similarity(sense1, sense2)

def similarity_by_infocontent(sense1, sense2, option):
    """ Returns similarity scores by information content. """
    if sense1.pos != sense2.pos: # infocontent sim can't do diff POS.
        return 0

    info_contents = ['ic-bnc-add1.dat', 'ic-bnc-resnik-add1.dat', 
                     'ic-bnc-resnik.dat', 'ic-bnc.dat', 

                     'ic-brown-add1.dat', 'ic-brown-resnik-add1.dat', 
                     'ic-brown-resnik.dat', 'ic-brown.dat', 

                     'ic-semcor-add1.dat', 'ic-semcor.dat',

                     'ic-semcorraw-add1.dat', 'ic-semcorraw-resnik-add1.dat', 
                     'ic-semcorraw-resnik.dat', 'ic-semcorraw.dat', 

                     'ic-shaks-add1.dat', 'ic-shaks-resnik.dat', 
                     'ic-shaks-resnink-add1.dat', 'ic-shaks.dat', 

                     'ic-treebank-add1.dat', 'ic-treebank-resnik-add1.dat', 
                     'ic-treebank-resnik.dat', 'ic-treebank.dat']

    if option in ['res', 'resnik']:
        return wn.res_similarity(sense1, sense2, wnic.ic('ic-bnc-resnik-add1.dat'))
    #return min(wn.res_similarity(sense1, sense2, wnic.ic(ic)) \
    #             for ic in info_contents)

    elif option in ['jcn', "jiang-conrath"]:
        return wn.jcn_similarity(sense1, sense2, wnic.ic('ic-bnc-add1.dat'))

    elif option in ['lin']:
        return wn.lin_similarity(sense1, sense2, wnic.ic('ic-bnc-add1.dat'))

def sim(sense1, sense2, option="path"):
    """ Calculates similarity based on user's choice. """
    option = option.lower()
    if option.lower() in ["path", "path_similarity", 
                        "wup", "wupa", "wu-palmer", "wu-palmer",
                        'lch', "leacock-chordorow"]:
        return similarity_by_path(sense1, sense2, option) 
    elif option.lower() in ["res", "resnik",
                          "jcn","jiang-conrath",
                          "lin"]:
        return similarity_by_infocontent(sense1, sense2, option)

def max_similarity(context_sentence, ambiguous_word, option="path", 
                   pos=None, best=True):
    """
    Perform WSD by maximizing the sum of maximum similarity between possible 
    synsets of all words in the context sentence and the possible synsets of the 
    ambiguous words (see http://goo.gl/XMq2BI):
    {argmax}_{synset(a)}(\sum_{i}^{n}{{max}_{synset(i)}(sim(i,a))}
    """
    result = {}
    for i in wn.synsets(ambiguous_word):
        try:
            if pos and pos != str(i.pos()):
                continue
        except:
            if pos and pos != str(i.pos):
                continue
        result[i] = sum(max([sim(i,k,option) for k in wn.synsets(j)]+[0]) \
                        for j in word_tokenize(context_sentence))

    if option in ["res","resnik"]: # lower score = more similar
        result = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in result.items()])
    else: # higher score = more similar
        result = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in result.items()],reverse=True)
    print result
    if best: return result[0][1];
    return result


bank_sents = ['I went to the bank to deposit my money',
'The river bank was full of dead fishes']
ans = max_similarity(bank_sents[0], 'bank', pos="n", option="res")
print ans
print ans[0][1].definition
```

Comment: Probably not worth an answer but you can replace : `return max(wn.path_similarity(sense1,sense2), wn.path_similarity(sense1,sense2))` with `return wn.path_similarity(sense1,sense2)`.

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, remove stop words from context sentence.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def is_stopword(x): return x not in stopwords.words('english')

words = filter(is_stopword,  word_tokenize(context_sentence))
result[i] = sum(max([sim(i,k,option) for k in wn.synsets(j)]+[0]) \
    for j in words)
```

nltk has below stop words currently,

> ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 'she', 'her', 'hers', 'herself', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'they', 'them', 'their', 'theirs', 'themselves', 'what', 'which', 'who', 'whom', 'this', 'that', 'these', 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'be', 'been', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 'do', 'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'because', 'as', 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at', 'by', 'for', 'with', 'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 'through', 'during', 'before', 'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 'out', 'on', 'off', 'over', 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 'will', 'just', 'don', 'should', 'now']

Stop words affect accuracy depends on algorithm you are using. I would suggest you should test stop words and algorithm with [Test Collection](http://wsd.nlm.nih.gov/).

Comment: actually, it's already remove inherently, just not explicitly in the code. WordNet doesn't have an synset for stopwords and hence it wouldn't give a similarity score when maximizing the similarity =)